# Is it possible that "when " can follow" if"?

Tags: sentence-construction

I'd like to know if "when" can follow "if", like this:

> I would like to know if when it is my turn (After standing in line for a long time) there will be still tickets on sale?

I don't think so, but I am m not sure, and I did not find any answer.

Comment: [J. M. Barrie *When a Man's Single* - A Tale of Literary Life:](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22if+when+he+was+smoking%22) ***If, when he was smoking in the grounds**, he saw Mary approaching, he covertly dropped his cigar.* Barrie's style is beyond criticism, so yours is fine too.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Barrie includes a comma though, which I recommend OP does as well. If this is speaking, it's fine

Comment: Do you understand how "if" and "when" function in this sentence? Do you understsand the role of "when it is my turn"? (Please edit your question to include what your research revealed about such things. Doing so will help you to get much more appropriate answers.)

Comment: I would like to know **whether** there will **still be** tickets on sale when I reach the window. (The tickets are not 'still'.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Barrie inclues two commas.  The two commas isolate the conditional phrase ', when he was smoking in the grounds,'

Comment: @charmer: Commas aren't really of any significance anyway, but there's certainly no need to include a comma in something like *If when you get to my house you find the front door is locked, just come round the back*. My guess is that *most* instances of ***If when you arrive...*** in Google Books don't have a comma.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Punctuation adds explicit clarity to the phrasing of many sentences, And a correctly placed comma can change the entire comprehension of the sentence  E.g.  
"lets eat grandpa" Vs "let's eat, grandpa"

Comment: @charmer: True language is spoken, not written. And there's a *huge* difference in how those two "grandpa" utterances are spoken, which cannot be avoided. In the case of ***when*** followed by ***if***, there are any number of spoken contexts where there's no pause between them, and it's a poor quality writer who introduces a comma on the grounds of some kind of syntactic rule that isn't axiomatically reflecting a spoken pause. Besides which, there's been an undeniable trend for well over a century to use less and lighter punctuation everywhere (downgrade period to comma, eliminate commas,..).

Comment: I just hope @FumbleFingers isn't in charge of any documentation relating to safety
written language reflects spoken language  reading the grandpa example from the page with no commas sure its clear how it should be said  you forget that this is an obvious example there are much less obvious phrases where if written without a comma will much more easily be misunderstood

Comment: @charmer: That's a cheap shot. I'm sure nobody writes safety manuals in such a way that a fleck of dust obscuring a comma makes the difference between life and death for grandpa!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've personaly came across this sort of error in manuals on more than one occasion.  many authors even technical authors and their editors have difficulty ignoring prior knowledge when proofreading (i.e. they read what they expect to read - and can and do easily miss where a sentence / instruction could be misconstrued and read the wrong way.

Answer (score 15):

A comma would help and may be mandatory.

> I would like to know if, when it is my turn, there will be any tickets for sale.

The phrase "when it is my turn" is parenthetical. It could be removed without changing the overall sense or grammar, so it should be set off with commas or brackets:

> I'd like to know if (when it is my turn) there will be...

The "when it is my turn" phrase gives the time, and isn't part of the conditional structure of the question. It could be moved for greater clarity:

> I'd like to know if there will be any tickets left, when it is my turn.

Comment: In the parenthetical position right after _if_, I’d say the comma is all but mandatory; but in final position, I’d omit it.

Comment: Nice answer, +1. But regarding  "*The "when it is my turn" phrase gives the time, and isn't part of the conditional structure*" --> there ***is*** no  conditional structure. That there *if* is being used as a normal interrogative marker. You can substitute it with *whether* and the meaning doesn't change (a good, quick test to differentiate the two uses of *if*).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [Google ngrams](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22if%20when%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1967%2Ccd_max%3A2019&lr=lang_en) for "if when" it appears that the two words do appear adjacent in a number of texts, **but** they are always separated either by a comma as in James K's answer or either written **if/when** or **if (when)**  denoting they are alternatives, that is an abbreviation of ""if or when"". I could not find an instance where they were not separated somehow.
There was also the construct **if;when** but this is when the words were forming part of a computer language statement, not English as such.

Comment: Those *if/when* and _if(when)_ occurrences are from conditional constructions. The OP's sentence involves an interrogative *if*, not a conditional one. The comma instances could be either.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I'm not disputing that. My point is that I could find no instance of the use of "if when" without some sort of punctuation between them. If you can provide a plausible example without a comma or bracket or other punctuation I'd love to see it.

Comment: My point is that the OP is asking about interrogative *if* + *when*. Most linguists and language teachers etc regard conditional and interrogative *if* (i.e. 'question'-*if*) as two distinct words, two lexemes. So, if that's true, the two *if*s, yours and OP's, are homophones, not instances of the same word.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking about conversational English, and the art of making it easy for someone to understand and answer your question.

It's always nice to be grammatically correct. But in a brief conversation like this, an even better skill is to be clear and succinct.

My suggestion is to keep it simple, and add a friendly greeting:

> Hi! Will there still be tickets for sale when I get to the window?

Don't forget to smile!

(Hat tip to Weather Vane for mentioning "the window" in a comment.)

While I've got you, a note about "on sale" vs. "for sale".

In American English, "on sale" often means "available at a discount", where "for sale" just means "can I buy it?"